# Getting the id/name of the td where the datepicker is called

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

We're using jquery.ui.datepicker in several forms on our application.
I need to implement logic based on only 2 of those instances. How can I get the name of the td where the datepicker is located? I've tried using the id from the datepicker, but that's a randomly generated id, so that won't consistently work. But is there a way to get the id of where the instance is?

My jsp looks like this:

```
<tr ><td id="s1startDate" class="text">
        <html:text property="user.startDate" styleClass="required date datepicker usDateFormat"/>
</td></tr>
```

In the datepicker code, I have:

```
/* Update the input field with the selected date. */
_selectDate: function(id, dateStr) {
    dpChk(dateStr, id);
    . .. . .
    .. . .
}
```

and in my js:

```
function dpChk(dateVal, id) {
   var startDate = new Date(dateVal);
   alert('id is ' id);
   ... . .
   . . . .
}
```

Comment: jQuery UI's datepicker doesn't have a `_selectDate` event or property ?

Comment: @adeneo It does, which is one I referenced above. There's an id that's created there, but id name is randomly generated, and I get a different id each time.

Comment: Well the [**documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) doesn't mention any such method, so it's hard to know how it works when it's clearly not documented, and [**testing**](http://jsfiddle.net/q69covdr/) it gets you nothing ?

Comment: Testing with the id that's passed in their _selectDate gets me ids like: dp1421419563454, dp1421419563455, dp1421419563452, dp1421419563453, etc. ..

Comment: It's a global event isn't it, called like `$.datepicker._selectDate = function ...`, probably should have included the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID you you're getting is the dynamic ID given to the input, to get the ID of the TD, target id

```
$.datepicker._selectDate = function (id, dateStr) {
    var td_id = $(id).closest('td').prop('id')
}
```